# Scene is Loading in Unity but unable to Load Scene in Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

My Game is working perfectly in Unity but when I export apk tp Android Mobile 2nd Scene doesn't load properly and does not work.

Please look at the image. It is the second Scene and not loaded properly and the Run button is not working which is working perfectly in unity play mode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K0ox.jpg)

CODES ARE BELOW

```
SCENE 1 CODE#

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
#if UNITY_ANALYTICS
using UnityEngine.Analytics;
#endif
#if UNITY_PURCHASING
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;
#endif

public class StartButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void StartGame()
    {
        if (PlayerData.instance.ftueLevel == 0)
        {
            PlayerData.instance.ftueLevel = 1;
            PlayerData.instance.Save();
#if UNITY_ANALYTICS
            AnalyticsEvent.FirstInteraction("start_button_pressed");
#endif
        }

#if UNITY_PURCHASING
        var module = StandardPurchasingModule.Instance();
#endif
        SceneManager.LoadScene("main");
    }
}

SCENE 2 CODE#

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.AddressableAssets;
using UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations;

#if UNITY_ANALYTICS
using UnityEngine.Analytics;
#endif

/// <summary>
/// State pushed on the GameManager during the Loadout, when player select player, theme and accessories
/// Take care of init the UI, load all the data used for it etc.
/// </summary>
public class LoadoutState : AState
{
    public Canvas inventoryCanvas;

    [Header("Char UI")]
    public Text charNameDisplay;
    public RectTransform charSelect;
    public Transform charPosition;

    [Header("Theme UI")]
    public Text themeNameDisplay;
    public RectTransform themeSelect;
    public Image themeIcon;

    [Header("PowerUp UI")]
    public RectTransform powerupSelect;
    public Image powerupIcon;
    public Text powerupCount;
    public Sprite noItemIcon;

    [Header("Accessory UI")]
    public RectTransform accessoriesSelector;
    public Text accesoryNameDisplay;
    public Image accessoryIconDisplay;

    [Header("Other Data")]
    public Leaderboard leaderboard;
    public MissionUI missionPopup;
    public Button runButton;

    public GameObject tutorialBlocker;
    public GameObject tutorialPrompt;

    public MeshFilter skyMeshFilter;
    public MeshFilter UIGroundFilter;

    public AudioClip menuTheme;


    [Header("Prefabs")]
    public ConsumableIcon consumableIcon;

    Consumable.ConsumableType m_PowerupToUse = Consumable.ConsumableType.NONE;

    protected GameObject m_Character;
    protected List<int> m_OwnedAccesories = new List<int>();
    protected int m_UsedAccessory = -1;
    protected int m_UsedPowerupIndex;
    protected bool m_IsLoadingCharacter;

    protected Modifier m_CurrentModifier = new Modifier();

    protected const float k_CharacterRotationSpeed = 45f;
    protected const string k_ShopSceneName = "shop";
    protected const float k_OwnedAccessoriesCharacterOffset = -0.1f;
    protected int k_UILayer;
    protected readonly Quaternion k_FlippedYAxisRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0f, 180f, 0f);

    public override void Enter(AState from)
    {
        tutorialBlocker.SetActive(!PlayerData.instance.tutorialDone);
        tutorialPrompt.SetActive(false);

        inventoryCanvas.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        missionPopup.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        charNameDisplay.text = "";
        themeNameDisplay.text = "";

        k_UILayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("UI");

        skyMeshFilter.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        UIGroundFilter.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        // Reseting the global blinking value. Can happen if the game unexpectedly exited while still blinking
        Shader.SetGlobalFloat("_BlinkingValue", 0.0f);

        if (MusicPlayer.instance.GetStem(0) != menuTheme)
        {
            MusicPlayer.instance.SetStem(0, menuTheme);
            StartCoroutine(MusicPlayer.instance.RestartAllStems());
        }

        runButton.interactable = false;
        runButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Loading...";

        if(m_PowerupToUse != Consumable.ConsumableType.NONE)
        {
            //if we come back from a run and we don't have any more of the powerup we wanted to use, we reset the powerup to use to NONE
            if (!PlayerData.instance.consumables.ContainsKey(m_PowerupToUse) || PlayerData.instance.consumables[m_PowerupToUse] == 0)
                m_PowerupToUse = Consumable.ConsumableType.NONE;
        }

        Refresh();
    }

    public override void Exit(AState to)
    {
        missionPopup.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        inventoryCanvas.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        if (m_Character != null) Addressables.ReleaseInstance(m_Character);

        GameState gs = to as GameState;

        skyMeshFilter.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        UIGroundFilter.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        if (gs != null)
        {
            gs.currentModifier = m_CurrentModifier;

            // We reset the modifier to a default one, for next run (if a new modifier is applied, it will replace this default one before the run starts)
            m_CurrentModifier = new Modifier();

            if (m_PowerupToUse != Consumable.ConsumableType.NONE)
            {
                PlayerData.instance.Consume(m_PowerupToUse);
                Consumable inv = Instantiate(ConsumableDatabase.GetConsumbale(m_PowerupToUse));
                inv.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                gs.trackManager.characterController.inventory = inv;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        PopulatePowerup();

        StartCoroutine(PopulateCharacters());
        StartCoroutine(PopulateTheme());
    }

    public override string GetName()
    {
        return "Loadout";
    }

    public override void Tick()
    {
        if (!runButton.interactable)
        {
            bool interactable = ThemeDatabase.loaded && CharacterDatabase.loaded;
            if(interactable)
            {
                runButton.interactable = true;
                runButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Run!";

                //we can always enabled, as the parent will be disabled if tutorial is already done
                tutorialPrompt.SetActive(true);
            }
        }

        if(m_Character != null)
        {
            m_Character.transform.Rotate(0, k_CharacterRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, Space.Self);
        }

        charSelect.gameObject.SetActive(PlayerData.instance.characters.Count > 1);
        themeSelect.gameObject.SetActive(PlayerData.instance.themes.Count > 1);
    }

    public void GoToStore()
    {
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(k_ShopSceneName, UnityEngine.SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    }

    public void ChangeCharacter(int dir)
    {
        PlayerData.instance.usedCharacter += dir;
        if (PlayerData.instance.usedCharacter >= PlayerData.instance.characters.Count)
            PlayerData.instance.usedCharacter = 0;
        else if(PlayerData.instance.usedCharacter < 0)
            PlayerData.instance.usedCharacter = PlayerData.instance.characters.Count-1;

        StartCoroutine(PopulateCharacters());
    }

    public void ChangeAccessory(int dir)
    {
        m_UsedAccessory += dir;
        if (m_UsedAccessory >= m_OwnedAccesories.Count)
            m_UsedAccessory = -1;
        else if (m_UsedAccessory < -1)
            m_UsedAccessory = m_OwnedAccesories.Count-1;

        if (m_UsedAccessory != -1)
            PlayerData.instance.usedAccessory = m_OwnedAccesories[m_UsedAccessory];
        else
            PlayerData.instance.usedAccessory = -1;

        SetupAccessory();
    }

    public void ChangeTheme(int dir)
    {
        PlayerData.instance.usedTheme += dir;
        if (PlayerData.instance.usedTheme >= PlayerData.instance.themes.Count)
            PlayerData.instance.usedTheme = 0;
        else if (PlayerData.instance.usedTheme < 0)
            PlayerData.instance.usedTheme = PlayerData.instance.themes.Count - 1;

        StartCoroutine(PopulateTheme());
    }

    public IEnumerator PopulateTheme()
    {
        ThemeData t = null;

        while (t == null)
        {
            t = ThemeDatabase.GetThemeData(PlayerData.instance.themes[PlayerData.instance.usedTheme]);
            yield return null;
        }

        themeNameDisplay.text = t.themeName;
        themeIcon.sprite = t.themeIcon;

        skyMeshFilter.sharedMesh = t.skyMesh;
        UIGroundFilter.sharedMesh = t.UIGroundMesh;
    }

    public IEnumerator PopulateCharacters()
    {
        accessoriesSelector.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        PlayerData.instance.usedAccessory = -1;
        m_UsedAccessory = -1;

        if (!m_IsLoadingCharacter)
        {
            m_IsLoadingCharacter = true;
            GameObject newChar = null;
            while (newChar == null)
            {
                Character c = CharacterDatabase.GetCharacter(PlayerData.instance.characters[PlayerData.instance.usedCharacter]);

                if (c != null)
                {
                    m_OwnedAccesories.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < c.accessories.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        // Check which accessories we own.
                        string compoundName = c.characterName + ":" + c.accessories[i].accessoryName;
                        if (PlayerData.instance.characterAccessories.Contains(compoundName))
                        {
                            m_OwnedAccesories.Add(i);
                        }
                    }

                    Vector3 pos = charPosition.transform.position;
                    if (m_OwnedAccesories.Count > 0)
                    {
                        pos.x = k_OwnedAccessoriesCharacterOffset;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pos.x = 0.0f;
                    }
                    charPosition.transform.position = pos;

                    accessoriesSelector.gameObject.SetActive(m_OwnedAccesories.Count > 0);

                    AsyncOperationHandle op = Addressables.InstantiateAsync(c.characterName);
                    yield return op;
                    if (op.Result == null || !(op.Result is GameObject))
                    {
                        Debug.LogWarning(string.Format("Unable to load character {0}.", c.characterName));
                        yield break;
                    }
                    newChar = op.Result as GameObject;
                    Helpers.SetRendererLayerRecursive(newChar, k_UILayer);
                    newChar.transform.SetParent(charPosition, false);
                    newChar.transform.rotation = k_FlippedYAxisRotation;

                    if (m_Character != null)
                        Addressables.ReleaseInstance(m_Character);

                    m_Character = newChar;
                    charNameDisplay.text = c.characterName;

                    m_Character.transform.localPosition = Vector3.right * 1000;
                    //animator will take a frame to initialize, during which the character will be in a T-pose.
                    //So we move the character off screen, wait that initialised frame, then move the character back in place.
                    //That avoid an ugly "T-pose" flash time
                    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
                    m_Character.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

                    SetupAccessory();
                }
                else
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
            }
            m_IsLoadingCharacter = false;
        }
    }

    void SetupAccessory()
    {
        Character c = m_Character.GetComponent<Character>();
        c.SetupAccesory(PlayerData.instance.usedAccessory);

        if (PlayerData.instance.usedAccessory == -1)
        {
            accesoryNameDisplay.text = "None";
            accessoryIconDisplay.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            accessoryIconDisplay.enabled = true;
            accesoryNameDisplay.text = c.accessories[PlayerData.instance.usedAccessory].accessoryName;
            accessoryIconDisplay.sprite = c.accessories[PlayerData.instance.usedAccessory].accessoryIcon;
        }
    }

    void PopulatePowerup()
    {
        powerupIcon.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        if (PlayerData.instance.consumables.Count > 0)
        {
            Consumable c = ConsumableDatabase.GetConsumbale(m_PowerupToUse);

            powerupSelect.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            if (c != null)
            {
                powerupIcon.sprite = c.icon;
                powerupCount.text = PlayerData.instance.consumables[m_PowerupToUse].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                powerupIcon.sprite = noItemIcon;
                powerupCount.text = "";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            powerupSelect.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void ChangeConsumable(int dir)
    {
        bool found = false;
        do
        {
            m_UsedPowerupIndex += dir;
            if(m_UsedPowerupIndex >= (int)Consumable.ConsumableType.MAX_COUNT)
            {
                m_UsedPowerupIndex = 0; 
            }
            else if(m_UsedPowerupIndex < 0)
            {
                m_UsedPowerupIndex = (int)Consumable.ConsumableType.MAX_COUNT - 1;
            }

            int count = 0;
            if(PlayerData.instance.consumables.TryGetValue((Consumable.ConsumableType)m_UsedPowerupIndex, out count) && count > 0)
            {
                found = true;
            }

        } while (m_UsedPowerupIndex != 0 && !found);

        m_PowerupToUse = (Consumable.ConsumableType)m_UsedPowerupIndex;
        PopulatePowerup();
    }

    public void UnequipPowerup()
    {
        m_PowerupToUse = Consumable.ConsumableType.NONE;
    }


    public void SetModifier(Modifier modifier)
    {
        m_CurrentModifier = modifier;
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        if (PlayerData.instance.tutorialDone)
        {
            if (PlayerData.instance.ftueLevel == 1)
            {
                PlayerData.instance.ftueLevel = 2;
                PlayerData.instance.Save();
            }
        }

        manager.SwitchState("Game");
    }

    public void Openleaderboard()
    {
        leaderboard.displayPlayer = false;
        leaderboard.forcePlayerDisplay = false;
        leaderboard.Open();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]. Also, this is not a valid use for the [tag:visual-studio] tag

Answer (score 1):

When you are building an APK file it can be splited to APK + OBB.

So, it is possible that you are trying to load a scene that is absent in your APK. You need to force the creation of the APK without the OBB. To do it you need to check Player Settings in Android, go to Publishing Settings and uncheck Split Application Binary.

Comment: thanks for your help I have double-checked but the Split Application Binary is already unchecked.